# Azure-Databricks autoloader Binaryfile option with foreach() gives java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-autoloader

I am trying to do copying file from one location to another location using BinaryFile option and foreach(copy) in autoloader. It runs well with smaller files(upto 150 MB) but fails with bigger files throws below exception :

```
*22/09/07 10:25:51 INFO FileScanRDD: Reading File path: dbfs:/mnt/somefile.csv, range: 0-1652464461, partition values: [empty row], modificationTime: 1662542176000.
22/09/07 10:25:52 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread stdout writer for /databricks/python/bin/python
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow.getBinary(UnsafeRow.java:416)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.SpecializedGettersReader.read(SpecializedGettersReader.java:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow.get(UnsafeRow.java:333)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvaluatePython$.toJava(EvaluatePython.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonForeachWriter.$anonfun$inputByteIterator$1(PythonForeachWriter.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonForeachWriter$$Lambda$1830/1643360976.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.next(SerDeUtil.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.next(SerDeUtil.scala:82)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:442)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:573)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$Lambda$2008/2134044540.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2275)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:365)
22/09/07 10:25:52 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[stdout writer for /databricks/python/bin/python,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow.getBinary(UnsafeRow.java:416)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.SpecializedGettersReader.read(SpecializedGettersReader.java:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow.get(UnsafeRow.java:333)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvaluatePython$.toJava(EvaluatePython.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonForeachWriter.$anonfun$inputByteIterator$1(PythonForeachWriter.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonForeachWriter$$Lambda$1830/1643360976.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.next(SerDeUtil.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.next(SerDeUtil.scala:82)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:442)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:573)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$Lambda$2008/2134044540.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2275)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:365)*
```

Below is the high-level code snippet for reference:

**Cluster size is 2 workers and 1 driver with 14 Gb ram and 4 cores each**

```
cloudfile_options = {
    "cloudFiles.subscriptionId":subscription_ID,
    "cloudFiles.connectionString": queue_SAS_connection_string,
    "cloudFiles.format": "BinaryFile", 
    "cloudFiles.tenantId":tenant_ID,
    "cloudFiles.clientId":client_ID,
    "cloudFiles.clientSecret":client_secret,
    "cloudFiles.useNotifications" :"true"
}

def copy(row):
    source = row['path']
    destination = "somewhere"
    shutil.copy(source,destination)

spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles")
                        .options(**cloudfile_options)
                        .load(storage_input_path)              
                        .writeStream
                        .foreach(copy)
                        .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_location)
                        .trigger(once=True)
                        .start()
```

I also tested shutil.copy with huge file sizes (20GB) outside foreach() and it works seemlessly.

Any leads on this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you're passing the full row that include the file content that should be serialized from JVM to Python. If everything you do is just copying the file, then just add `.select("path")` before `.writeStream`, so only file name will be passed to Python, but no content:

Comment: Thanks for the response. Haven't seen any issues with by selecting path alone. We also have decompression logic which deals with file content incase of compressed files otherwise , we just copy to the different destination.. Is there any hard memory limit for row['content']. if so, Is there a way to fine tune that?